# How to rewrite custom title and description only for blog in WordPress using child theme functions.php

Tags: wordpress, blogs

How can I rewrite meta title and description in Wordpress using child theme functions.php?

I want to rewrite it only on main blog page (for example: www.example.com/blog), where I have listed all articles.

The problem is that the main theme already adds title and description to blog page. So I need to remove them first and then add custom ones.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you using any SEO plugin? If not, an SEO plugin like Yoast or All-in-One-SEO will provide such functionality.

Comment: No, I am not using SEO plugin. The main theme adds custom titles and descriptions so I wanted to change it using child theme so if there will be an update I will not lost my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, WordPress does not add a `<meta name=decription>` tag. That is usually done by a seo plugin like Yoast, therefor the method for overriding it differ per plugin. Or theme.

You might be a able to change these texts in the wp-admin settings, again depending on the plugin/theme.

The title you should be able to change using this example:

```
function SO_52811727_wp_title($title) {

    // see https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags for more options
    if ( is_archive() ){
        $title = 'custom title';
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'SO_52811727_wp_title', 100);
```

Comment: This solution works, I only had to change the if condition - instead of is_archive I used is_home. Thanks.

Comment: Could you also help me with description? I used similar code, but right now I have two meta descriptions on blog page. How can I remove the current one and add the custom one?

Comment: That entirly depends on the plugin/theme that add the `meta` Do you know which one add that?

Comment: The custom theme adds this meta tag. I am not using plugin for this. It seems that this theme adds the same description from one of my articles. So I have duplicate descriptions on my page - one is used on main blog and another one is used in one of my articles.

Comment: I recommend asking the theme author, especially if it's a paid theme. It should be added by some kind of `add_action('wp_head', ...........)`